# Spacebar issue in a form

Tags: jquery, slider

I have two div(s) with different IDs.

First div has a jquery slider and another have a contact us form.

When ever I press space in text field or text area in contact us form div, the jquery slider transit the next picture.

Can any body help me out in this issue.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is a third part control I'm
>   guessing that they have hooked up some
>   events to navigate using the keyboard.
>   Try checking the API for that control
>   to see if there are settings so taht
>   you can disable keyboard input.

You need to do this:

```
var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
    enableKeyboardNavigation:  false, // Specifies whether keyboard navigation is enabled
}
```

Comment: I am using jquery galleriffic-2.0, can you guide that in which file i can change ?

Comment: modified my comment. Should help :)

Comment: Issue resolved.

I have disabled action on space button from js file.

Comment: Now that the issue is solved please mark this as the answer :) I hope your project goes well.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
// Setup Keyboard Navigation

if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation) {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {

        var target = e.target || e.srcElement; // hack
        //disable navigation on an input editable element
        if (target && target.type) return true;         

        var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
        switch(key) {
            case 32: // space
                    gallery.next();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
            case 33: // Page Up
                gallery.previousPage();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 34: // Page Down
                gallery.nextPage();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 35: // End
                gallery.gotoIndex(gallery.data.length-1);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 36: // Home
                gallery.gotoIndex(0);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 37: // left arrow
                gallery.previous();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 39: // right arrow
                gallery.next();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
        }
    });
}
```